# Share a folder from terminal osx

Tags: macos, network-shares, shared-folders

There's a few ways to supposedly do this, but none of them work for me. I would like to share a folder located at `~/Desktop/Folder` using samba, meaning that it would be accessible from `smb://192.168.x.x/Folder` on another computer. I also need to set a custom password for it.

`sudo sharing -s ~/Desktop/Folder` does nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo sharing -s 001 ~/Desktop/Folder`? The man page says the -s switch needs a flag, 100 for afp only, 010 for ftp only and 001 for smb only.